# Libvirt guests on isolated network cannot ping each other

Tags: ping, arp, libvirt, virtual-network

I am trying to create a network with following topology. Because I need a custom Gateway and the network is small, I do not want to use DHCP on the isolated network.

```
 ┌─────────────────┐                ┌──────────────────┐
 │                 │                │                  │
 │     Guest 1     │                │     Guest 2      │
 │                 │                │                  │
 └────────┬────────┘                └────────┬─────────┘
          │10.20.0.15                        │10.20.0.20
 ─────────┴─────────────────┬────────────────┴──────── isolated
                            │10.20.0.10
                   ┌────────┴───────┐
                   │                │
                   │     Gateway    │
                   │                │
                   └────────┬───────┘
                            │ 
                 ───────────┴────┬───────── default
                                 │
                       ┌─────────┴────────┐
                       │                  │
                       │       Host       │
                       │                  │
                       └──────────────────┘
```

The isolated network's XML is

```
<network>
  <name>isolated</name>
  <uuid>e66e50be-9ecb-11ee-a07e-870199a7fddd</uuid>
  <bridge name='iso0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:49:27:d4'/>
</network>
```

The guests have the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.20.0.15  # in Guest 1, 10.20.0.20 in Guest 2
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        gateway 10.20.0.10
```

And yet when I `ping 10.20.0.20` from Guest 1, I get nothing. ARP table shows `? (10.20.0.20) at <incomplete>  on eth0`. Same happens for Guest 2 to Guest 1, Gateway to either, etc.

`tcpdump` shows outgoing arp requests from the sender, but nothing on the receiver. To me this reads "the devices are not on the same virtual ethernet network" but I don't know how to troubleshoot this further. Any advice would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT** It seems like changing the NIC device models from `virtio` to `e1000e` solved the issue, although I do not understand why.

---

**EDIT 2** Put the NICs back to `virtio` and it still works. I did not make any other changes, restart host, etc. Very strange.

Comment: Have you checked how the network is behaving after a complete shutdown/restart or reboot? Does your network keep working reliably after a restart?